Errors in temp VM when importing a VHDX/raw in Google Cloud
I'm running a gcloud compute images import command to import a VHDX image (also tried with a .raw version) with a Windows 10 x64 OS on it. When I look at the serial console log for the temp VM that Google Cloud creates for this import, I see the following log lines:
Jun 25 18:00:50 inst-importer-inflate-ryqqq google_metadata_script_runner[976]: 2024/06/25 18:00:50 logging client: rpc error: code = PermissionDenied desc = Request had insufficient authentication scopes.
Jun 25 18:00:59 inst-importer-inflate-ryqqq OSConfigAgent[979]: 2024-06-25T18:00:59.0915Z OSConfigAgent Error policies.go:194: Error performing apt changes: exit status 100
Jun 25 18:01:00 inst-importer-inflate-ryqqq google_osconfig_agent[979]: 2024/06/25 18:01:00 logging client: rpc error: code = PermissionDenied desc = Request had insufficient authentication scopes.
Jun 25 18:01:12 inst-importer-inflate-ryqqq OSConfigAgent[979]: 2024-06-25T18:01:12.9881Z OSConfigAgent Error inventory.go:88: packages.GetPackageUpdates() error: error getting apt updates: exit status 100
Jun 25 18:01:13 inst-importer-inflate-ryqqq google_osconfig_agent[979]: 2024/06/25 18:01:13 logging client: rpc error: code = PermissionDenied desc = Request had insufficient authentication scopes.

My import takes forever and then times out. Do I need to resolve this error on the temp VM first before the import can go through? If yes, what are some things I can try?  I've already given the cloud service account the following roles:
[Service Account Admin, Service Account Token Creator, Service Account User, Cloud OS Config Service Agent, Editor] which I thought would be sufficient. It's hard to decipher from the error what specific permissions I might be missing.
Command:
gcloud compute images import build-agent-test \
        --source-file="gs://<path to vhdx file>.VHDX" \
        --cloudbuild-service-account=<account>@developer.gserviceaccount.com \
        --compute-service-account=<account>@developer.gserviceaccount.com \
        --log-location=gs://<path to logs> \
        --os windows-10-x64-byol \
        --no-guest-environment --timeout=24h --byol

Any help is appreciated, thanks!
